# How ot remove a jquery function from textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a asp.net textbox to which i assign datepicker when the search by option is Date, I want to unbind the datepicker function when the search by option changes to something else other than Date. Below are the code.

```
           $("#<%=ddlSearchBy.ClientID%>").change(function () {
                var cboValue = $("#<%=ddlSearchBy.ClientID%>").find("option:selected").text();
                if (cboValue == "Date") {
                    $("#<%=txtSearchBy.ClientID%>").datepicker();
                }
                else {
                    $("#<%=txtSearchBy.ClientID%>").removeData("datepicker");
                }
            });
```

Here i don't know what to do in the else part of the change event. I googled alot for this problem but did not find any solutions. If anybody can help me

Comment: Why don't you simply have more than one control? Hide and show the relevant ones instead of trying to change that control itself?

Comment: Thank you sir. This solution of yours worked.

Answer (score 0):

`datepicker` has a "method" for that:

```
$("#<%=txtSearchBy.ClientID%>").datepicker("destroy");
```

You can find it in [the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-destroy).

Comment: Sir i haven't used jQuery UI datepicker. I have used some other plugin which i have downloaded from the internet. The solution you provided above doesn't work for me. I am looking to sort of unbind this datepicker function from the textbox.

Comment: @AjmalAmirzad: Then you need to consult the documentation for that other date picker. If you use `datepicker` in a question you've tagged `jquery` and don't explicitly say you're not using the jQuery UI `datepicker`, well, people are going to understandably assume that you are.